# Continue Tekton pipeline after failure (similar to jenkins pipeline catchError behaviour)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, tekton, tekton-pipelines, openshift-pipelines

I have a pipeline where I want to:

1. provision some resources,
2. run some tests,
3. tear down the resources.

I want the tear down task, in step 3, to run **regardless** of whether tests passed or failed, in step 2. As far as I’ve understoood [runAfter](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/master/docs/pipelines.md#using-the-runafter-parameter) only runs a task, if the previous task succeeded.

I tried looking into [Conditions](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/master/docs/conditions.md), but can’t seem to find an example…

Anything else I can use or some example someone could point me to ?

Answer (score 7):

"finally" clause is implemented in Tekton Pipelines (Apr'20)

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: pipeline-with-final-tasks
spec:
  tasks:
    - name: pre-work
      taskRef:
        Name: some-pre-work
    - name: unit-test
      taskRef:
        Name: run-unit-test
      runAfter:
        - pre-work
    - name: integration-test
      taskRef:
        Name: run-integration-test
      runAfter:
        - unit-test
  finally:
    - name: cleanup-test
      taskRef:
        Name: cleanup-cluster
    - name: report-results
      taskRef:
        Name: report-test-results
```

Design document: Design doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxpYQHppiWOxsn4arqbwAFDo4T0-LCqpNa6p-TJdHrw/edit#

Comment: It is available in `v0.15.0` release indeed

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is not yet supported in Tekton, at the time of writing.

It is, however, work-in-progress in the [tektoncd/pipeline](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline) project, in [this PR](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pull/2437).